# Is there a name for this feeling?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, emotion, personality, behaviorism

With the intent of being seen as a big shot, a person induces unsuspecting observers to underestimate them by intentionally failing in trivial tasks but then successfully completing more complex tasks.

Comment: Sorry for my incompetence in English and psychology. It may not be categorized as a feeling but i believe it is connected to psychology. I think this trait comes under one of the dark triad in psychology ‘Machiavellianism’. People with this psychological trait will try to manipulate others if they think it would be beneficial. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The emotions may include: duplicitousness, slipperiness, artfulness, craftiness, deviousness, wiliness, cunningness, deceitfulness, slyness, sneakiness, crookedness, vanity, haughtiness, pretentiousness, affectation, conceitedness, smugness, superciliousness, bumptiousness, condescension, obstreperousness, grandiosity, hubris.

Comment: Thank you for editing. It would be helpful if you could suggest me some books to study human behavior.

Comment: What aspect of human behaviour are you interested in?  My own journey began with 'The Psychology Of Interpersonal Behaviour' by Michael Argyle.  ISBN 9780140172744  https://www.amazon.com.au/Psychology-Interpersonal-Behaviour-Michael-Argyle/dp/0140172742

Comment: Psychological behaviorism, personality types, emotions, cognitive psychology and reverse psychology. Thank you in advance.

Comment: My personal recommendation is 'The Psychology Of Interpersonal Behaviour' by Professor Michael Argyle.  An easy reading introduction from which you can explore further.